# AWS - is this possible? - redirecting to different index.html page by ip-

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

My website has 3 versions of languages in English, Korean, and Japanese. I have my whole static website stored in s3 bucket and will try to host it from there. What I want to do is, when people type in my webpage address like somepage.com, people in Korea to be redirected to the Korean index.html page, people in Japanese to be redirected to the Japanese index.html page in another directory, and people outside those two countries to be redirected to English index.html page. Would it be possible to do this for a static website stored in s3?

Comment: for the 3 languages you have same name `index.html` but they are in different path, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  Each are located as someweb.com/index.html, someweb.com/kr/index.html, someweb.com/jp/index.html.

Comment: I believe you can use routing policy in AWS Route 53 to divert traffic to specific endpoint based on the  origin of the request. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/geolocation-routing-policy/

Comment: I will definitely try this in near future. Thank you for your help